# Unable to handle back button navigation issue in hybrid apps

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

We have developed an hybrid app using phonegap in pure HTML stack (HTML, css, javascript). Currently we are facing issue with device back button navigation. Generally in any native apps such as android, on pressing back button the app moves to first screen and then exits the application or exits directly. But, we are not sure on how to handle this behaviour in angular js. As per current behaviour, in our application on pressing back button, it moves to previous screen and then to its previous and thereby navigates to different screens without exiting. So, we are not sure on how to handle this behaviour.

Comment: can you provide code ?

Comment: I don't have a specific answer but you could check how this is handled in ionic framework for example, as ionic uses angular directives on top of cordova, like you

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

in the onBackKeyDown method, navigate where you want or your login.